# Fractional part expansion of $\frac{1}{(e^{x}-1)^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

What's the fractional part expansion of 
$$\frac{1}{(e^{x}-1)^{2}}$$
I know that:
$$\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+2\pi i n}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: You'd be well advised to look into the continued fractions equivalents for this expression...of course for $x \gt 1$ the original expression is already between $0$ and $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+2\pi in}-\frac{1}{2}$

$f'(x)=-\frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}=-\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+2\pi in)^2}$

$-\frac{1}{e^x-1}- \frac{1}{(e^x-1)^2}=-\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+2\pi in)^2}$

$\frac{1}{(e^x-1)^2}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+2\pi in)^2}-\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+2\pi in)^2}-\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+2\pi in}-\frac{1}{2}  \right)$

$\frac{1}{(e^x-1)^2}=\frac{1}{2}+\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{(x+2\pi in)^2}-\frac{1}{x+2\pi in}\right)$